# Connect store and local IProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm kinda new to React/Redux with TypeScript and I'm "blocked" with my App.

Context:
I'm trying to display a variable from my Redux Store in my Component depending on the value of a variable got from Parent Component (thus in local Props typed IProps here).
Since TypeScript includes a lot of typing, I don't know how to type my Component (and monstly my mapStatetoProps function to connect everything).

Here is some of my code:

[My IProps and my Component declaration + error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmQld.png)

> Property 'payloadCompany' does not exist on type 'Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.

My mapStateToProps function + Export

```
function mapStateToProps(state:any, ownProps: IProps) {
return state.mainReducer;}
```

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GCI_Profile_Block_Content);`

Please let me know about my error(s) and orientate me on the good things to do

EDIT #1:
After a console.log(this.props), I can find the "missing" variables in it.

EDIT #2:
[The Parent Component Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51vxg.png) ->
This error is showing up after typing the variables in the child component:

> Type '{ id: number; titles: StringObject; payload: StringObject | undefined; options: { titlePrefix: boolean; }; mode: any; modeChange: (mode: string) => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<ClassAttributes<GCI_Profile_Block_Content> & IProps, "payload" | "titles" | "options" | "modeChange" | "mode" | ... 5 more ... | "key">': payloadCompany, payloadProfessional, payloadPersonnal

UPDATE FINAL:
After putting <any, any> as my Component type and defining the 3 variables in the IProps (while not touching the rest of the code), it's working

Comment: try to log the value of this.props to see what is in your props

Comment: great, now try to add payloadCompany in type IProps like you did with other props

Comment: Doing that:
Component seems okay but parent isn't good since I'm not sending payloadCompany via local Props but store

Comment: can you provide the code of your parent component?

Comment: If Header Component works fine, so Content Component should also work, so if you pass header to type IProps in parent and child(Block_Header), do this logic with props in Content Component and add the rest props in both Parent and Child Components

Comment: Header is not using Store, so it's not imported here sadly